# socket programming Vs inter-task communication

Tags: operating-system

what is the difference between socket-programming and inter-task communication

How can inter-process communication can be achieved in linux and vxworks ?
In which scenario we need inter-task communication and inter-process communication ?

please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

You should read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

In a nutshell, socket can be used for local or network communication. Inter Task communication(like shared memory) can only be used for processes running on the same host.